# RestKit/CoreData not saving relationships immediately to the persistent store

Tags: core-data, restkit

Does RestKit or CoreData has some weird mechanism of context save? I mean I download my Managed Objects and if I kill the app quickly and run it again I see that some relationship objects are not saved to persistent store. However when I wait like 10-15 seconds before killing the app these object get saved and I can fetch them when running the app again.

So how does it work? Is it normal that the objects are not saved in transaction-like operation (either the whole object with its relationships or nothing)?

Maybe I was just lucky with these 15 seconds and it is possible that these relationship objects wont be saved at all in some circumstances due to some bug in CoreData/RestKit/my code?

I download objects using:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[manager getObjectsAtPath:@"/" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    NSLog(@"OK");
    [self saveContext];

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR");
}];
```

And save context by:

```
[[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext save:&err];
```

Any help?

Comment: Could you explicitly perform the save operation in the main queue? Just to be sure..

Comment: I'm checking [[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread] when saving and it always equals YES. What's strange is that main object (Order) is saved but it's subobjects (Items) are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestKit saves the context for you before calling the success block - you do not need to explicitly save.

By "kill the app" I guess you are stopping it in Xcode? This is a full termination and anything that isn't quite finished yet will not get a chance to. This is unrealistic testing and you shouldn't base much on it.

If you want to know exactly when a save operation has completed, observe the appropriate notifications that are posted.